# Sum of table column by cell name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have a table, table headers and some number under the header.

I want to write a dynamic formula which will get the sum of the column under each header.

instead of

```
=SUM(Subeler[MERKEZ OFIS])
```

I want a formula to replace the name of the header, something like :

```
=SUM(Subeler["C6"])
```

the header is on C6 cell.

Why I need this :

1. each time the header may change which is coming from powerquery
2. I need the sum, somewhere on the top of the table

Comment: Can't you just creat a dynamic named range and use it. Since your powerquery only changes the name cell (C6), you can keep using your named range in your SUM fonction.

Comment: the names of the headers cannot be dynamically changed , some of them just disappear or appear if there is a data in the database...

Answer (score 1):

in C5 cell , i wrote the formula

> ="Subeler["&C6&"]"

then in the cell i have this formula :

> =Sum(indirect(c5))

it was so simple but i've just figured it out...

Comment: What is the content of C5?

Comment: @NiteshHalai **="Subeler["&C6&"]"**

Comment: Oh.. I see the same is already written in your answer. Sorry for that. I was also using the indirect function but I was trying to combine everything in one formula and failing. Thanks for sharing the answer

Comment: Nope I solved it now. I simply replaced C5 in the formula you used with "Subeler["&C6&"]"  which gave me this: =SUM(INDIRECT("Subeler["&C6&"]")).